# Using Sencha Command in Aptana

Tags: sencha-touch, aptana, sencha-command

Is there an existing solution for using Sencha command (to create app or controllers etc...) directly from the Aptana IDE. Any help will be welcome...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no existing solution for that. However, you can anyway create an app or files with sencha command. And that the process is pretty simple.

Guide for reference: [Sencha command](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen and that's not complicated but it was in case of something exists it would be easier